# How to present a tabview controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i have a tab based application
what i have done is put another view as the welcome screen and i've made it to load first, the problem is i dont know how to call the tabview controller from the view i have created.

the presentmodal view controller it only show the firstview

this is what i have in my .m file

```
-(IBAction) next_OnClick
{
  FirstView *f=[[FirstView alloc] init];
  [self presentModalViewController:f animated:YES];

}
```

Please tell me the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you wanna show the welcome view only at the first launch? I think it's better to show the welcome view as a modalview.

Comment: i'm showing the welcome screen firs my problem is how do i show the tab view from the welcome screen??

Comment: How are you showing up the welcome screen? Did you modify the app delegate?

Comment: yes the app delegate is modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When FirstView (it should be called FirstViewController) decides it's time to go away, it can do this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```